# register_rest_route with method POST but in wp-json/<plugin-name> is showing GET

Tags: rest-api

I register my REST APIs "filter_user2" and "testing_rest" with method **POST** but it is registered as **GET** method in the wp-json/plugin-name. Anyone know what could be the problem? What I have done is refresh empty cache and hard reload, restart server, restart pc but result is still the same.

[image]

wp-json/plugin-name

[image]

Comment: nevermind. my "method" is supposedly to be "methods".

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! For future reference: please don't put code in your questions as an image, but as text, which will make it easier to read and possibly diagnose any problems. (Glad you found your solution, too!)